# What are the applications in Kali Linux that has low storage usage when screen recording?

Tags: linux, screen-recording

I am looking for applications for Linux that can screen record with low storage usage.

I was using Kazam, but it uses too much storage when saving screen recordings (13 mins = 600+ MB).

Comment: HI, what do you mean by "low storage"? It depends on the quality of the video no matter which software you choose. This needs more details, such as settings ou want to record with (e.g., 1080p 60fps).